# static final vs an instance final when and why? Java interview question

Tags: java

Suppose we have

```
final double pi = 3.14159
```

- Should we make above statement static or not?
- When we'd want static final vs an instance final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should make it static final yes. Possibly public or private... but that's another discussion
2. In general static finals should be constants or threadsafe objects (such as immutables) that you will construct only once and use across multiple instances of classes.
3. Instance finals are if you are using it only in that instance, but (wisely) prefer to reduce your state mutability as much as possible.
4. The two are not necessarily contradictory. For example, you might have a PasswordComplexityPolicy class. This takes a constructor of a bunch of options, all of which are private final instance. But at the top of the class we also have a final public static PasswordComplexityPolicy DEFAULT_POLICY=new PasswordComplexityPolicy(all the stuff needed to construct). Because it's threadsafe, other consumers may choose to use this preconstructed policy rather than build their own. Good for them!

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are bound to the class, so they're created once and use only one spot in memory. For universal constants such as PI, that's perfect.

Instance variables are part of the object instance, so they are stored once per object.
DO NOTE, however, that final variables don't need their value specified in the code. They can perfectly be calculated in the constructor. As such, they are useful when the constant is specific for the object's instance. (Say, you have a Character object that reads its movement speed from a file during creation, but that speed never changes afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

Static final is used for constants like the example you show.
Instance final is used for inmutable classes.

Answer (score 0):

The static final is initialized (stays in memory) when the class is loaded while the instance final is initialized everytime an instance is created. So for this case static final would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Since pi never changes you should use static final here. You'd use an instance final when it's defined as part of the constructor and not known at compile time. If it's always the same value and known at compile time it should be a static final.

Answer (score 0):

Use `static` when you need only one copy of the constant. If you need a copy for each instance of the class, leave off the `static`.